# Adding dynamic content to a webpage: using a table, divs, or lists?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

When adding dynamic content to a webpage, is it better to add this by just adding a new row to a table, by adding a new div element, or adding a list element?

For example, if I wanted a posting of content to be added to a page when a user submits it, kind of like an ebay listing, or like reddit. When a user submits an "offer", the offer will be shown on the page, under all previous offers. What element would make the most sense to stick this information in?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the information. It doesn't matter if you are adding the content dynamically or writing static HTML - it's the same question.

You can get the answer by probing the type of the data:

1. for list data (ordered or unordered) - use a list
2. for tabular data - use `table`
3. for other data - consider `div` (or other tags like `section`, `footer`, `article` etc.)